# Deployment from git repo that doesn't have appspec.yml using aws codedeploy

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, devops, aws-code-deploy

I have a Git repo that is maintained without an `appspec.yml` file.

How can I use [CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy) in this case?

How do I write in [AppSpec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html) file to download a file from an S3 URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deploy without the appspec file. The deploy will fail.

As an alternative you can bundle the repo as a zip package, add an appspec, and then register the revision and deploy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , But I canot modify the source repo is there anyway i can trigger an automated git repo creation that i can include the appsec file and set of other files  . Basicly creating a new git / bitbucket repo as changes are pushed in source git master branch

Answer (score 0):

An Appspec file is required for a Codedeploy deployment. Below are some useful documentation on integrating Codedeploy with Github.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-github.html